# This query works well in Mysql but in Postgres it is giving error

Tags: laravel, postgresql

This query works fine when I was using Mysql, now that we've migrated to Postgres, it's giving an error. Where is the problem?

```
public function scopeClosestTo(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query, array $coord = null)
{
    if ($coord && isset($coord['longitude'], $coord['latitude'])) {
        return $query->select([
            '*',
            'distance' => DB::table( 'offers as offers_temp' )->selectRaw(
                'ST_Distance_Sphere(point(`longitude`, `latitude`), point(?, ?)) AS distance',
                [$coord['longitude'], $coord['latitude']]
            )->whereColumn('offers_temp.id', 'offers.id')
        ])
            ->withCount(['favoriteOffers'])
            ->where('published', '=', true)
            ->where('active', '=', true)
            ->whereNotNull('longitude')
            ->whereNotNull('latitude')
            ->whereDate('expires_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now())
            ->orWhereNull('expires_at')
            ->orderBy('distance');
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Error:

> "SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","\nLINE 1: ...ct *, (select ST_Distance_Sphere(point(`longitude`, `latitud...\n                                                             ^ (SQL: select *, (select ST_Distance_Sphere(point(`longitude`,` latitude`), point(-43.3722344, -22.7867144)) AS distance from "offers" as "offers_temp" where "offers_temp"."id" = "offers"."id") as "distance", (select count(*) from "favorite_offers" where "offers"."id" = "favorite_offers"."offer_id" and "favorite_offers"."deleted_at" is null) as "favorite_offers_count" from "offers" where (("published" = 1 and "active" = 1 and "longitude" is not null and "latitude" is not null and "expires_at"::date > 2022-03-28 or "expires_at" is null) and "longitude" is not null and "latitude" is not null and exists (select * from "offer_categories" inner join "offers_offer_categories" on "offer_categories"."id" = "offers_offer_categories"."offer_category_id" where "offers"."id" = "offers_offer_categories"."offer_id" and "offers_offer_categories"."offer_category_id" in (1) and "offer_categories"."deleted_at" is null) and "to_companies" = 0 and "published" = 1 and "active" = 1 and "expires_at"::date > 2022-03-28 or "expires_at" is null) and "offers"."deleted_at" is null order by "distance" asc limit 15 offset 0)"

Comment: What is `\Carbon\Carbon` supposed to be?  **Add answer as update to question**.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that looks like the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) date library.

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses backticks to escape column names, which works in MySQL. However, PostgreSQL uses double quotes to escape column names.

Change

```
point(`longitude`, `latitude`)
```

To

```
point("longitude", "latitude")
```

However, the words `longitude` and `latitude` are not reserved words in postgres, so there should be no reason you need to quote them.

---

See [this article on the PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL) for more about moving from MySQL to PostgreSQL.